# Unable to login after registration

Tags: functions, wp-admin, login, user-registration, wp-login-form

I use wp_insert_user to register new users from the frontend.
But when I use wp_signon to log them in later, it fails. It says the username or password is wrong. But they are not (password: pass).

Only admin and any other user created through the admin dashboard are able to log in.

Here's the code
AJAX Call

```
import $ from "jquery";

class Login {
  constructor() {
    this.events();
  }

  events() {
    const warningText = document.getElementById("warningMsg");
    document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {

      $.ajax({
        url: simple.ajax_url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          action: "ajaxlogin",
          email: document.getElementById("email").value,
          password: document.getElementById("password").value,
          security: document.getElementById("login_security").value,
        },
        success: (response) => {
          if (response.loggedin == true) {
            console.log(response);
            location = location;
          } else {
            console.log(response);
            const errormsg = "Wrong Username or Password";
            document.getElementById(
              "warningMsg"
            ).innerText = errormsg.toUpperCase();
          }
        },
        error: (response) => {
          warningText.classList.toggle("d-none");
          warningText.innerText = "SOMETHING WENT WRONG. TRY AGAIN!";
          console.log(response);
        },
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}

export default Login;
```

functions.php

```
function get_username($email) {
  $user = get_user_by('email', $email);
  return $user->data->user_login;
}

function ajax_login(){

  // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
  check_ajax_referer('ajax-login-nonce', 'security');

  $login = get_username($_POST['email']);
  $pass = $_POST['password'];

  // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
  $info = array();
  $info['user_login'] = $login;
  $info['user_password'] = $pass;
  $info['remember'] = true;

  $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
  if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
    echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
  } else {
      echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
  } 
  die();
}

// Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
```

This is the signup code I used
functions.php

```
function ajax_signup(){
  // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
  check_ajax_referer('ajax-signup-nonce', 'security');

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $rnd_str = sprintf("%0d", mt_rand(1, 999999));

  // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
  $info = array();
  $info['user_login'] = $username.'_'.$rnd_str;
  $info['user_nicename'] = $username;
  $info['first_name'] = $username;
  $info['display_name'] = $_POST['displayName'];
  $info['user_email'] = $_POST['email'];
  $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
  $info['role'] = 'student';
  $info['show_admin_bar_front'] = 'false';

  $user_signup = wp_insert_user($info);
  if (is_wp_error($user_signup)){
      echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Something went wrong. Try again please')));
  } else {
    $user = get_user_by('id', $user_signup);
    if($user) {
      wp_set_current_user($user_signup, $user->user_login);
      wp_set_auth_cookie($user_signup);
      do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login, $user);
    }
    echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Success. Logging in.')));
  }

  die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxsignup', 'ajax_signup' );
```

Comment: I'd guess you're setting the password wrong in the wp_insert_call then. Can you show us that code? Does the password hash look correct in the database, and does it match 'pass' using wp_check_password? if it does, there's probably something else wrong with the user and the login is being rejected: it would then be useful to debug the login code e.g. add error_log()s to trace, to see where your sign ons are being rejected.

Comment: I have added the code above. I tried wp_check_password but that also returns false although the password is correct (password is pass).

Comment: I meant the wp_insert_user code, because that's what I'd guess you've got wrong. (In particular that takes 'user_pass' not 'user_password'.) If wp_check_password returns false then you're definitely not setting the user's password correctly.

Comment: I have added the code. Please take a look.

Comment: Yes, it should be `$info['user_pass'] =` not `user_password`

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed it